# team services online - sync error

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I am using Visual studio 2013 community edition and try to access code base from Team services online in Git version.

I am able to clone source base from master repository. I make changes and commit to local. Whenever I try to push back the changes to server, I am getting an error

"An error occurred. Detailed message : Error while copying content to a stream."

Any idea? what might be wrong? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Ok..I had somehow missed the credential manager. I submitted my login details in Git Credential manager and Sync worked perfectly fine